# PhpSpreadsheet add a list to specific cell

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I have to code a php script which will write some values in a spreadsheet.
PhpSpreadsheet will be used for this work.

First, is it possible to write in a existing file without overwritting the existing strings and formulas?
==> I guess yes by using IOFactory

Some cells should be a list based on a specific area.
I mean exactly the same as using "Data validation" in Excel?
Is it possible to do that? And how? 
I havent't read anything about that...

Thanks for your help.
Regards,

Comment: Look into the fputcsv() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php). the fopen accepts a parameter `a+` which stops the values being overwritten everytime the file is opened.

Comment: If you set a value for a cell that already has content, then it will overwrite that existing content.... it's up to your code to append a value to a cell

Comment: And the [PHPSpreadsheet documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell) has a section on setting data validation on a cell

Comment: Indeed, I read too fast. Anyone knows how to set the index of the list? I mean, ok, I have created the list with the range technique but then how can specify to begin the list on a specific value. Let's say I have Element1, Element2, Element3 in the list. How should I do to show Element2 when the file is openend instead of a blank cell ?